# MeetingRequest.ChangeHighlights is null

Tags: c#, .net, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS Managed API 2.2.1.0 (C#, .NET) to connect the Microsoft Exchange Online Service (Office365 Subscription)

In my Outlook inbox, there is a meeting invitation which has a changed meeting time and location. (old time and location are crossed out. new time and location are highlighted in red)

When I query using EWS Managed API, the ChangeHighlights property of the MeetingRequest is null.

I tried all the options of ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion). Including:
Exchange2013, Exchange2013_SP1, Exchange2015, Exchange2016, V2015_10_05

Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 4.7

```
foreach (Item mailitem in findResults)
{
    if (mailitem.GetType() != typeof(MeetingRequest))
        continue;

    MeetingRequest message = MeetingRequest.Bind(exchange, mailitem.Id);

    bool locationChanged = message.ChangeHighlights.HasLocationChanged;
}
```

I expect to the locationChanged will be true.

But, I found the property ChangeHighlights is null. The code goes into error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange won't return that property by default as part of the FirstClassProperties so you need to define a PropertySet and explicitly add that property for it to be returned eg

```
                PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                psPropset.Add(MeetingRequestSchema.ChangeHighlights);
                MeetingRequest Meeting= MeetingRequest.Bind(service, itItem.Id,psPropset);
```